# Html.DropDownListFor selected value is not setting as selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

My code to print a dropdown is like this

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.LevelTwo,
        new SelectList(""),"My selected value", new { @class = "custom-select" })
```

This gives me an output like this

```
<select class="custom-select"   id="LevelTwo" name="LevelTwo">
<option value="">My selected value</option>
```

But I want it to be something like this

```
    <select class="custom-select"   id="LevelTwo" name="LevelTwo">
<option selected="selected" value="My selected value">My selected value</option>
```

How can I achieve this?
Note: Other elements of the dropdown will be added later using Ajax. Which won't disrupt above explained usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n=> n.LevelTwo, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{ Text= "My selected value", Value= "My selected value" }}, new { @class = "custom-select" })
```